# SQL: Update columns based from a matched pattern in a same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table 'Accounts'. The entries below are all in the same table. I need to update entries based on a matched pattern. Notice the Ids have same pattern except after the underscore.

The old accounts statuses will change to inactive. For the new accounts, their statuses will change to active and their emails will be updated to the ones from the old accounts that matches the Id pattern.

Also, if there are new accounts that have identical patterns like for example X65423_KEL and X65423_KEL1, the email column of both entries would still be updated based on what is stored in X65432_REL.

FYI: The entries are already stored in the table. So All I just need is to update the entries.
[image: Image here]

Comment: Please explain the "id pattern".  What happens when there are multiple matches on the same id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know if an account is "old" or "new"? Why is `'KEL'` and `'OTK`' new and `'REL'` and `LET'` old?

Comment: @Larnu You would know through their statuses. Old accounts are active and new ones are inactive before updating. This is somehow like a one-time update script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how big your Accounts table is or if there are additional columns you have to update.  But given your data set one approach is to pull out the Active data and then apply it once for new accounts and then once for the old ones.  Such as:

```
CREATE TABLE #Accounts(ID varchar(10), email varchar(50), Status varchar(10))


INSERT INTO #Accounts VALUES('X65423_REL','test@gmail.com','Active')
INSERT INTO #Accounts VALUES('X32562_LET','test2@gmail.com','Active')
INSERT INTO #Accounts VALUES('X65423_KEL','default@gmail.com','Inactive')
INSERT INTO #Accounts VALUES('X32562_OTK','default@gmail.com','Inactive')



SELECT ID, LEFT(ID, charindex('_', ID) - 1) LK_ID, Email
INTO #LookUp
  from #Accounts
  WHERE Status = 'Active'

UPDATE #Accounts
SET email = t2.email, Status = 'Active'
from #Accounts t1
INNER JOIN  #LookUp t2 on  LEFT(t1.ID, charindex('_', t1.ID) - 1) = t2.LK_ID
where t1.Status <> 'Active'

UPDATE #Accounts
Set Status = 'Inactive'
from #Accounts t1
INNER JOIN #LookUp t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's comment *"You would know through their statuses. Old accounts are active and new ones are inactive before updating. This is somehow like a one-time update script"* this seems that it's therefore as simple as:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET [Status] = CASE [Status] WHEN 'Active' THEN 'Inactive'
                             WHEN 'Inactive' THEN 'Active'
                             ELSE [Status] END;
```

That will change **every** inactive account to active and **every** active account to inactive. If they have a different `status`, they will be unchanged.

Comment: This is why `text` data is infinitely better than an image of text, @RichardHubley.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done in single query.
Tested on **MySQL** **5.7.24**

```
UPDATE accounts,
(
  SELECT email as old_email FROM accounts
  WHERE status = 'active'
) as temp
SET email = temp.old_email, 
    status = (SELECT IF(status = 'active', 'inactive', 'active'))
```

Comment: My the OP has tagged SQL Server... SQL Server <> MySQL.